# Internal border on ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, border, internal

I would like to put an internal border on my ImageView, I managed to do an external one with padding and background but I want my image to keep the same size (even if a part of it is coevered by a border) so what I need is to make an internal border but I can't figure out how to do it, any suggestions?

[image]

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Your ImageView has fixed size or not ?

Comment: How can I know if it's fixed size or not? I tried to change its width/height programmaticly but it didn't do anything. My ImageView has wrap_content in both width and height but is inside a layout that have a weight at 0.2 (I think that's why the size doesn't change). I could put my xml here but it's quite complicated (they're "include" inside "include"..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mBorder"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

mBorder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

   <stroke android:width="4dp"
    android:color="#ff00ffff" />

</shape>
```

Comment: This is the solution ! Thank you. Just one thing, add "<solid android:color="@null" />" to mBorder.xml to avoid covering the ImageView with a black background.